# tar -C with certain files in the direcory

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, tar

Let's say I have two directories that I would to `tar` without retaining the directory structure:

```
/root/dir1
/root/dir2
```

- Also, I would like to backup only files that begin with say f1 in /root/dir1 and a file called log.txt in /root/dir1
- In /root/dir2 I only want files that begin with f2

How I can achieve that?

Comment: you can use the command `find` and `tar` together something like `find mydir -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "f1" -print0 | xargs -0 tar cvf mydir.tar`

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU tar, you can use the `--transform` or `--strip-components` options to get a flat archive, without the directory tree. Something like:

```
tar cf foo.tar --transform='s:.*/::' /root/dir1/f1* /root/dir2/f2* /root/dir1/log.txt
```

GNU tar will warn about the leading `/` in the file names, but we're removing them anyway.

Alternately, with a couple of `cd`s:

```
cd /root/dir1;
tar cf /some/where/foo.tar f1* log.txt
cd /root/dir2;
tar uf /some/where/foo.tar f2*
```

Here, we'll need to specify a path to the tar archive that won't be affected by the `cd`s (so an absolute path, or since both are directories in `/root`, a path to the parent folder).